# Is there a way to prove to a visitor that a serverside does what it did previously?

Tags: web-applications, hosting

Is there a way to prove to a visitor of a web page that an open-source serverside application hosted on a Webserver is completly unmodified (without malicious code)? The app has to be server-side, client-side is not possible. Are there any hosting providers that confirm that only a unmodified script is running?

e.g. confirming that a random number generator does not store its calculated values.

Answer (score 0):

No, no client user can be guaranteed the server is "Without malicious code". In fact you can have a website hosted without the website itself being infected, while having malicious programs doing other things on your server without your knowledge. If you did not write the code to an executable and it was executed, you can not guarantee it wasn't malicious.

Answer (score 0):

You should narrow your question. First, like Jake has mentioned, a server can do malicious stuff to *others* (say, send spam) without any interaction with a visitor that reveals it. So, what you can ask about is: "can a user be sure that the running script doesn't do anything wrong with the visitors data or doesn't attack them provided that an initial open-source script doesn't?"

But that's still not narrow enough. Say, the script was generating some code from some high-level pattern (which is a user's input) and the generation is done on server-side. Than you can't be sure that the output code is not malicious unless you haven't input the exactly same stuff before and got a different output (if you got the same output, it doesn't tells anything since the malicious code can be inserted only for some inputs).

What one can check is if the http response is the same (same html and other resource are given as a response). But to do that, one has to store the previous response which can't be done in a non-techy way unless there's a client-side app. Moreover, the only case when one may think the response is absolutely safe is when at least there's no further interaction with the server (ajax calls etc) and checking that is not a simple task.

So in fact you have to add a client side app and even in that case, there can be very rare occasions when it can absolutely be sure that the server is ok. Afterall, if the server-side didn't change (no stored data?), it is natural to create a client-side app.

You may get more helpful answers if you narrow the topic: what is your server-side supposed to do?